# How to install ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop on Windows 7 (64bit)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, arcgis-10.2, windows-7

I am going to install ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2 but I cannot find a tutorial about how to do that!

Does anyone have any advice on how to install this software?

Answer (score 4):

Please check out http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/quick-start-guides/10.2/ for details.